# Installing JasperSoft takes forever

Tags: software-installation

I extracted `TIB_js-jrs-cp_7.1.0_linux_x86_64.run` which I downloaded from [the JasperSoft site](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server/releases) and executed it. The installer started and completed successfully almost all the steps, but at the end of the installation it says

> Creating Sample Database: sugarcrm - This may take a few minutes

But I have waited for approximately 30-40 minutes already. Is this normal? It seems it is stuck for me, I might be wrong, though.

[image: install dialog]

Answer (score 1):

See [Jasperreports-server-installation-guide](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-installation-guide/v630/binary-installer-freezes): the installer creates a log file in `<js-install>/installation.log` (don't let it scare you; it will be JAVA errors ;) )

From the link:

> Installer Log Files
>
> If you get an error when running the JasperReports Server installer on any platform, look at the log file created by the installer. This log records the status and completion of installer operations. If a specific error occurred, you may find an explicit error message. Even without an explicit error message, the log file should help you locate the cause of the error.
>
> You'll find the installer log for your platform in the following location:
>
> Windows

```
<js-install>/installation.log
```

> Linux

```
<js-install>/installation.log
```

> Mac

```
 <js-install>/installation.log
```

> If you've tried multiple installs, make sure you view the most recent install log. Then you can submit the installation.log to Jaspersoft Technical Support.

Comment: I have unfortunately killed the application and restarted the installer, skipping the creation of a sample database. This way it was successful.